# Understanding the command : Make distclean

Tags: makefile, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gnu-make

Can someone elaborate the following command how does it work?

```
distclean: mrproper
    @find $(srctree) $(RCS_FIND_IGNORE) \
        \( -name '*.orig' -o -name '*.rej' -o -name '*~' \
        -o -name '*.bak' -o -name '#*#' -o -name '.*.orig' \
        -o -name '.*.rej' -o -size 0 \
        -o -name '*%' -o -name '.*.cmd' -o -name 'core' \) \
        -type f -print | xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `$make distclean` is issued,

[find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command will search the files in $(srctree) with mentioned extensions.

```
@find $(srctree) $(RCS_FIND_IGNORE) \
        \( -name '*.orig' -o -name '*.rej' -o -name '*~' \
        -o -name '*.bak' -o -name '#*#' -o -name '.*.orig' \
        -o -name '.*.rej' -o -size 0 \
        -o -name '*%' -o -name '.*.cmd' -o -name 'core' \)
```

then absolute path of each file is taken using `-print` option and type of file as regular file using `-type f`.

```
-type f -print
```

Result of find result will be redirected to `rm` command to delete that file. While redirecting the `find` command result to `rm` command, you need to pass the file name one by one(This is not rm -r dirname). so [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) is used to read from stdin and build the command.

some useful links about xargs.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/ 
[Understanding the UNIX command xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898044/understanding-the-unix-command-xargs) 
http://linux.101hacks.com/linux-commands/xargs-command-examples/

some links to find command
http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/10-examples-of-using-find-command-in-Linux/67264
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-linux-find-command-examples/ 
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-unix-linux-find-command-examples-part-2/

Comment: thanks very nice explanation. why @ is added before find command.

Comment: thanks for the various links . they are really useful.

Comment: Just remove @ symbol before find. you will see the difference. :)

Comment: yes. to avoid printing command unnecessarily, @ will hide it.

Comment: what is the `mrproper` for?