# How to process files in nested directories?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make my JavaScript files a little smaller.

I've got a `javascripts/` directory, and then a `_website/javascripts/` directory where my static assets get compiled. Inside of the `javascripts/` directory I have a few nested directories for polyfills, libraries and so on, and then files for my site.

How can I recursively iterate through all the nested directories of `javascripts/` and pump out minified, compressed, but not concatenated files into my `_website/javascripts/` directory?

Here's the code I have so far. Ideally I can do this in an npm script. It's totally cool if it only works on Linux for now.

```
find scripts/ -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 uglifyjs
```

And then I don't know how to pass the inputs to each xargs execution as names for the --output flag of uglifyjs.

How do I do this with xargs? Is it the {} notion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing this:

`find javascripts/ -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file uglifyjs file -o _website/file`

So, `find` scurries around looking through everything in `javascripts/`. Every time it finds something with the name ending in `.js` it sends writes that to STDOUT. The `|` accepts those writes and sends them into `xargs`.

(The `-print0` flag on find makes sure not to add new lines or extra spaces. The `-0` flag on xargs, makes sure to handle each whole output from find, even when file names have new lines or spaces and such in them.)

The `-I file` creates a variable `file` which holds the filename which it got form each of the outputs from the `find` command. Then we use that variable in `uglifyjs file -o _website/file` to run uglify on each js file and drop it in the appropriate place in our compiled website directory `_website`. Small note: it's possible this won't automatically create new directories in `_website/javascripts`. Haven't tested that.

Best of luck to anyone who comes around here!

Comment: You may want to look into `-exec` action of `find` rather than piping to another program...

Comment: I got  `find: missing argument to `-exec'` `find scripts/ -name '*.js' -exec uglifyjs {} -c -o _site/{}` how do I replace the file names in the uglify part of the call?

Comment: Put ` \;` at the end of it (space backslash semicolon)

Comment: Woohoo! That's even better : )

Answer (score 1):

To recursively iterate, you can use the `globstar` option on a newer version of bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

for file in javascripts/**/*.js
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    uglifyjs "$file" > "_website/javascripts/$name"
done
```

Also you were missing a semicolon before `do` (necessary if your code is on one line) and missing the `done` at the end.

Comment: Updated my code to this `find scripts/ -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 uglifyjs` but not sure how to access each input of xargs so I can specify the files to output.

Comment: Was there a problem with my answer? Did it not work for you? I notice one typo that I just fixed.

Comment: It's a great answer! I just think I have limited bash syntax knowledge. There are multiple asterixis. I needed and answer on one line and I wasn't quite sure how to convert yours. I went looking elsewhere and sorta mixed a bunch of different things I learned and tested the approach I listed in my answer.